# discontinuous functions integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How come that some jump-discontinuity functions are integrable at the discontinuity?  wouldn't that contradict with the fact that if a function has a jump discontinuity at some point then it is non differentiable at such point ? (i think my ignorance really kicks in here) ..
However, i find that some discontinuous functions are integrable and others are not, how is that? 
like this problem for example: if f(x)=0 while x is any rational number and f(x)=1 while x is any irrational number prove that f in non integrable on [0,1] ?
how is that different from a step function (for instance) ?

Comment: observe that a jump at a single point has measure zero...

Comment: Maybe you meant $f(x)$ to be some other value when $x$ was rational, apart from $0$. In this scenario, there are infinitely many discontinuities within any finite interval. Such a function is not integrable.